# Change src of iframe with an input box on another page

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, src

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Homepage: have a search bar/input field that inputs into an string (src of iframe) on another page.
The site is PHP. I do not know what all files I will need.

On homepage:

searchbox

Other page with iframe I need the input from search to

```
<iframe src="https://www.tradingview.com/e/?symbol= 'SEARCHBOX CONTENTS' >
```

The people using the site will know to enter a ticker symbol (stock symbol).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: My crystal ball can't find any of your codes.. hmmm maybe you have to pay more! to see what you have done to accomplish your goals. Maybe some html at least? Also your post seem to be a bit unclear. :)

Comment: Sorry! I did not indent :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? If so, please note you will need to handle some security checks.
on the input string.

```
<?php  //create a php page and name it what ever

  $iframe = null;

  if (isSet ($_POST ['submit']))
  {
      if (!empty ($_POST ['search']))
          $iframe = "<iframe src='https://www.tradingview.com/e/?symbol={$_POST ['search']}'' width='800' height='600'>";
  }

?>

<form method="post" action="">
 <input type="text" name="search"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="searc">
</form>

<?php echo $iframe; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may `POST` your searchbox input into a php or a php page that contains the `iframe` that you mean.
for example : 
i consider you have a form :

```
<form action='frame.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='keyword'><input type='submit' value='search'>
</form>
```

Your `frame.php`:

```
<?php 
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
echo "<iframe src='$keyword'></iframe>";
?>
```

That's all if you just want to fill `src` attribute of an `iframe`.
But, I think it would not working properly, because `src` of an `iframe` must be a link to a file (included it's filename and extension). so if it's just a keyword, you have to process the keyword before you attach it into `src` atrribute.

I suggest you to use jquery, ajax, and json if you want your web page looks more dynamic